# Smooth slide down to anchor on document load

Tags: javascript, jquery

The idea behind is that Server generates div's with unique ID's (that act as anchors). How do I smoothly scroll down to those ID's, by getting them from the browser URL? Code sample is included:

```js
try {
  if(window.location.hash) {
    const location = window.location.hash;
    const parentNode = $(location).parent();
    parentNode.addClass('item active');
  }
}
catch (e) {}
```

For now, everything works, however it is a rapid jump to that anchor. How do I make is smoother?

Comment: Try this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section2

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line to your `html` CSS

```
html {
    scoll-behavior: smooth;
}
```